# jQuery(...). is not a function in Wordpress Custom Templates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the AnimatedModal JS library to allow users to login on my Wordpress site.

In my **functions.php** I have enqueued as follows:

```
function smallium__enqueue_scripts() {
    //lets put in the animated modal
    wp_enqueue_script( 'medium-modal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/animatedModal.min.js', array( 'jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_style('animated-modal', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'medium-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/medium-front.js', array( 'jquery','medium-modal' ) ); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smallium__enqueue_scripts');
```

In the **medium-front.js** I call the animatedModal() function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#login-anchor").animatedModal();
}
```

This works fine on most pages except for Custom Wordpress templates I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).animatedModal is not a function
```

In the source code on all pages, the library is correctly encoded before I make the function call, so I'm not sure why only on custom templates this doesn't work.

I've also created an empty template file with only the header and footer included, to see if any code could cause the error, to no avail.

```
<?php
/* Template name: Write */
get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: probably you are calling the function "animatedModal" before loading the file(plugin file) into page

Comment: Ready function behaves differently in WP, try to call the function in end footer and you will have the results. after that you can use window load event or just place script in the footer

Comment: looks pretty obvious that the element `#login-anchor` is not present when the code is executed, make sure that the HTML element is there.

Comment: @DavinderKumar This cannot be the solution. I have mentioned in my post that the call to the function is happening after the function is initialised.

Comment: @JoseAPL Regardless of whether the element exists or not, JS throws this error because it can't find the function, not because the element doesn't exist. This element only loads for logged-out users. If I view the homepage, with the element missing, it does NOT throw the error.

Comment: Brother, but function is in ready function, just check once after put it out from ready function

Comment: @DavinderKumar It does not work. The issue is that this only occurs on custom templates and NOT all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local `animatedModal.min.js` should be loaded before `</body>` instead of in the `<head>`, as documented [here](https://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/):

```
function smallium__enqueue_scripts() {
    //lets put in the animated modal
    wp_enqueue_style('animated-modal', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'medium-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/medium-front.js', array( 'jquery','medium-modal' ) ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'medium-modal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/animatedModal.min.js', array( 'jquery'),false, true ); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smallium__enqueue_scripts');
```